# Android Live-wallpaper: Accessing resource folder

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-activity, resources, live-wallpaper

I'm currently stuck at making a live background using opengl ES2.

Inside my renderer i want to access textures and shaders from the resource folders, but i cant  find a way to do that.

My current attempts at this have only resulted in crashes.

```
return new SurfaceRenderer((Activity) this.getApplicationContext(), WallpaperService.this);
```

It is the first paramenter in the the SurfaceRenderer constructor im struggeling with!

Later these variables will be used to access files like this:

```
final int resVertex = activity.getResources().getIdentifier(input+"_vertexshader","raw", activity.getPackageName());

    int resID = activity.getResources().getIdentifier(path,"raw", activity.getPackageName());
    InputStream inputStream = activity.getResources().openRawResource(resID);
```

Etc..

Where activity is the first parameter in the SurfaceRenderer constructor, and ctx the second one!

Any solutions to this?

Edit:
Trying to implement the solution, but im still having issues!

This is my renderers constructor:

```
public SurfaceRenderer(GLWallpaperService activity, Context ctx) {
    this.activity = activity;
     cc = activity;

    shaderlib = new ShaderLib(activity, ctx);
}
```

Which is used to forward the activity to my shader creation object, that eventually runs this:

```
inputStream = activity.getContext().getAssets().open(filename);
```

There is no getcontext function available, and when i try to make one, i only end up with a nullpointer, on this very command, any solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GLWallpaperService` can be used as a context. When you create renderer you can pass your `GLWallpaperService` implementation to renderer instance and use it to access */assets* folder.

Sample code from renderer class:

```
public BaseRenderer(Context context, IWallpaper wallpaper) {
    mContext = context;
    mWallpaper = wallpaper;
}

...
is = mWallpaper.getContext().getAssets().open(filename); 
...
is = mContext.getAssets().open(filename);
...
```

`mWallpaper` is an instance of custom `GLWallpaperService` in renderer class. This is code from my wallpapers.
By setting passed context to local `mContext` member you can use this context anywhere you need to access resources.

Comment: Thanks, going to try out this when i get home!

Comment: Hi, trying to implement your solution, but i am having issues. Explained them in OP, any solutions?

Comment: @user1419305 I've added more code samples. As you see, I pass context to constructor of renderer. Then you can use context either by getting it from wallpaper (it has a cusom getContext() method) or by assessing saved context. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

You can place your resources in Assets folder and use AssetManager to access it.

Comment: Thanks! combined with the answer underneath, i belive this may solve my problem!